# What's with the Community-blocking?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, protected-questions

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-sharp-listt-or-ilistt?lq=1). It's well structured, it's got 200+ votes and the accepted answer also has 200+ votes. Even so it's been protected by 'Community' for low-quality answers. I don't know about you, but that does not look like it has any low-quality answers. They may be short but they are concise and well-thought.

> Obviously if you are being asked which you use in an interview, you say IList, smile, and both look pleased at yourselves for being so clever. Or for a public facing API, IList. Hopefully you get my point. - *part of an answer by Arec Barrwin*

That is funny, not low-quality. What is with the 'protection'? Is it autonomous and if so, shouldn't it be fixed? If not, why would these answers be classified as low-quality?

Comment: The protection message says: "This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site."  That isn't really an evaluation of the existing answers.

Comment: @jonsca Then every question should be protected.

Comment: How does that follow from my statement? I think you are making a mountain out of a mole hill here.  Show that you can create another quality answer that gets an upvote and you'll be all set.  At this point, you've answered nothing on the site, so how can the system trust you to make an additional contribution to a question that is well-saturated with good content?

Comment: There's no need to protect a question unless it's already getting crap answers.  If a 15K user thinks that a question needs to be protected sooner, then that can be done.  Lower-traffic sites may be more likely to attract *good* answers from new users, so protecting every question preemptively would not be a good idea.  There is a reason why this privilege requires quite a bit of rep.

Comment: Wow. Everyone's a fan of possible duplicates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Community auto-protects because of **deleted** answers from low-rep users. It has nothing to do with the visible content on the page. There are currently five deleted answers on that post, all five of which were posted by users who *would have* been blocked if the protection had been in place earlier.

That is why it is protected. It has shown a track record of gathering crap from new users, so new users are no longer allowed to post answers on that question.

Comment: But now it is OK and therefore should be removed from protection.

Comment: @eshansingh1 What makes it ok now? Past evidence shows that if the protection gets removed, it will just start attracting crap again.

Comment: **Inevitably, every question will always attract one or two crap comments and/or answers.** We can't fix that. We just have to deal with it. *From past evidence,* it is clear that this question will be highly useful for the community. No protection required, just the lookie-outie of our users.

Comment: What's your point though? No one is arguing its usefulness - that has absolutely no bearing on it being protected. Protection is a preventive measure to keep out new answers from new users.

Comment: *What'syour point though? No one is arguing its usefulness.* Except me. *Protection is a preventitive measure to protect new answers from new users.* Apparently only high rep users (which by the way is a very ineffecient way to represent expertise) are of value on this site. Moreover a crap user can easily gain 10 rep.

Comment: 10 reputation is a very easy threshold to reach if someone has a legitimate answer to post there. Those who aren't interested enough to achieve a single answer upvote were probably nit going to contribute anything of value there anyways. You seem more confused about what protection means. A protected question does not mean that the content isn't useful, it means that **crap content** keeps getting posted there and we're trying to prevent it. That crap content has already been removed though, so you won't see it on the page.

Comment: But they can just as easily ask or answer a newbie question somewhere and then start posting crap.

Comment: @eshansingh1: sure but that's more effort. Protection isn't 100% perfect but it's mostly good enough.

Comment: That's not a lot if you are a human.

Comment: You have to realize that on popular questions like that, a vast majority of visitors come from search engines. A person who is going to troll the site with crap aint gonna go around to specific questions posting it. A random person off Google who doesn't understand our site or our quality standards might be inclined to post some random thing there and disappear. That's who we're targeting.

Comment: I'd actually +1 that if I could.